# InvocationTargetException on running my java spring-boot project

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to run this project on my localhost: https://github.com/callicoder/spring-boot-postgresql-jpa-hibernate-rest-api-demo

I cloned the project in my local system. Changed the required fields in my application.properties file. The **mvn dependency:tree** runs fine.
**mvn spring-boot:run** throws an error.

The error is:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFysn.png)

My **application.properties** is:

```
## Spring DATASOURCE
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres_demo
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

Let me know what else is required to get this code running.

My **javac version** is: 12.0.1

My **java version** says:

```
java version "1.8.0_202"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.202-b08, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no JAXB in the classpath. Try adding:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

This is the version that is needed by Hibernate version 5.4.x.

Comment: Try also adding jaxb-impl artifact

Comment: Could you please provide me the full dependency?

Comment: I added the following dependency, still facing the same issue:

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
     </dependency>